# HTML to PDF convertion using ABCpdf tool

Tags: .net, pdf, abcpdf

I am trying to convert a HTML page to PDF using ABCpdf component. I have used AddImagehtml method to do that. It is working. My requirement is that to get the values dynamically. How can I pass the values from my dataset to HTML.
Could anyone resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Build the HTML dynamically in a stringbuilder E.g.

Pseudo Code Below

```
String Builder SB = new StringBuilder()
// Initialize HTML here with head body, etc 
SB.AppendLine("<table>");`
foreach datarow DR in DataTable`
{
// loop through columns and add them in TR TD tags
}
// Now build the PDF from the HTML
Doc thisPDF = New Doc();
Integer iChk = thisPDF.AddImageHtml(SB.ToString());
while thisPDF.Chainable(iChk)
{
thisPDF.Page = thisPDF.AddPage();
thisPDF.FrameRect();
 iChk = thisPDF.AddImageToChain(iChk);
}
// Save the PDF here, or output to HTTP stream for user to download
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it dynamically on server side using other method like creating a dynamic table and looping through you data set to add the values.

Check the small table example and Large Table example in ABC PDF documentation in your installation folder.